# Specify the last args

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, args

I have created a discord.js bot and i was thinking so making a translator and i wanted to get the messages last args.

```js
client.on("message", async (message, args) => {
  if (message.content.startsWith(`${config.bot.prefix}ts `)) {
    const args = message.content
      .slice(config.bot.prefix.length)
      .trim()
      .split(/ +/g);
    let tmsg = args[1];
    let lang = args[2];
    translate(tmsg, { to: lang })
      .then((res) => {
        const tldmsg = res.text;
        message.reply({
          embed: {
            title: "Translated",
            description: `${tldmsg}`,
            fields: [{ name: "Translated to", value: `**Language: **${lang}` }],
            footer: {
              text: `Requested by ${message.author.username}`,
            },
            color: config.bot.color
          },
        });
        //console.log(res.text); //translated language
        //console.log(res.from.language.iso); //language converted
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  }
});
```

this is my code in the args[2] i want that to be the very last args of the message.

Comment: provide how commands look like `ts {lang} {trans content}` is this right ?

Comment: it will look like t!ts {message} {lang}

Comment: you said it the opposite way @HellCatVN

Answer (score 1):

You can get last the last one with Array.prototype.pop()

```
client.on("message", async (message, args) => {
  if (message.content.startsWith(`${config.bot.prefix}ts `)) {
    const args = message.content.trim()
      .slice(`${config.bot.prefix}ts `.length)
      .trim()
      .split(' ');
    let lang = args.pop();
    let tmsg = args.join(' ').trim();
    // translate
  }
});
```

Comment: And if you ever want to get the last element of an array without mutating use `<Array>[<Array>.length - 1]`